# Adding object Id to an array of object Ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Even after I add `post._id` to user posts array, the posts array is still empty. Please help me find the error. I want to populate the posts array later using the object Id.

User.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    posts:[{
        type :mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Post'
    }]
});
 
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Post.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/PostsDB",{useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
const PostSchema={
Title:String,
Content:String,
Author:{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
};
const Post=mongoose.model("Post",PostSchema);
module.exports=Post;
```

app.js

```js
app.post("/compose",function(req,res){
  const post=new Post({
    Title:req.body.postTitle,
    Content:req.body.postBody,
    Author:req.user._id
    });
    post.save();
    User.findOne({_id:req.user._id}).then(function(result,err){
      console.log(result);
      console.log(typeof post._id);
      result.posts.push(post._id);
    }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
    res.redirect("/");
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just pushing `id` into the array but you are not saving it back again into the the DB.
so once you pushed the `id`, make use `save` function to save updated value or you can use update query like [mongoose update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)

```js
app.post("/compose",function(req,res){
  const post=new Post({
    Title:req.body.postTitle,
    Content:req.body.postBody,
    Author:req.user._id
    });
    post.save();
    User.findOne({_id:req.user._id})
      .then(function(err, result){
         console.log(result);
         console.log(typeof post._id);
         result.posts.push(post._id);
         result.save();   //<------- added save method call
      })
      .catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
    res.redirect("/");
})
```

Also as a suggestion, use `err` as a first argument in callback function